# Create a function to normalize columns to earliest value using tidyverse?

Tags: r, lapply, tidyverse, dplyr, rollapply

The dataframes I work with have an arbitrary number of variables, and are of arbitrary length.  I'd like to create a function to normalize each column by its earliest value.  I'm new to R/tidyverse, and thought a for loop would work:

```
 Col.norm <- function(df){
             for (i in c(2:ncol(df))) {
             select(df,i) %>%
             mutate(df[]/df[[1]])
             }}
```

A representative df with a date column and 3 variables looks like this:

```
Z <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2018-06-01"), as.Date("2018-06-11"),   "days"), A = c(5:15), B = c(6:16), C= c(7:17))
```

Running the above function on that df gives the following error:

"Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Any help would be greatly appreciated - not sure how to loop after doing the select step...I've spent a ton of time on this...

Answer (score 0):

```
Col.norm <- function(df) {
  mutate_at(df, -1, funs(. / head(., 1)))
}
```